# How to serialize array of custom objects and post as json with jax-rs ClientBuilder?

Tags: java, jackson, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to figure out how to serialize an array of java objects and post as json with jax-rs ClientBuilder using jersey and/or jackson.

I'm using the ClientBuilder to do a post.  If for example you have an Arraylist of Car objects

```java
List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
```

And I want to do something like:

```java
Response response = ClientBuilder
.newClient.target(url)
.request()
.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
.post(Entity.json(cars));
```

and post exactly this as the payload

```
[{"brand": "toyota"}]
```

How would I need to implement the Car object?  And how would I need to setup my ClientBuilder chain properly?

Comment: _"How would I need to implement the Car [class]?"_. Have `String brand` field with getters and setters. Make sure you have jersey-media-json-jackson dependency..

Comment: Having it wrapped in an arraylist wont cause a problem?

Comment: No. Why don't you just try it?